# How to get the NAME OF an INSTANCE in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, signals, instance

I have build a class "Queue" in node.js. I need some queues, so i make instances like "orderQueue": `var orderQueue = new queue();`.

When the last element in a queue was processed, the queue should emit a signal like "orderQueue-processed" `process.emit(instance.name + "-processed");`, which should be handled by my main program `process.on(myobject.name + "-processed", function(){ addmorework ();});`

But up to now i have not found out how i can get the **name of the instance**. Answers in stackoverflow do something with the window object, but it's not a bowser, it's node.js.

May be the idea to use the name is not good. A recommendation what to use instead and is easy to handle would be also very welcome.

Answer (score 0):

There are two possible approaches to this that don't involved the name of the queue.

1. have your queue object act as an [`EventEmitter`](https://nodejs.org/api/events.html#events_class_events_eventemitter), so your main program creates instances of the queue, and then registers an event listener on it:

   ```
   var orderQueue = new queue();
   queue.on("processed", function() {
       // Do something when this specific queue has been emptied
   });
   ```
2. Or, pass the object object as the event data:

   ```
   process.emit("processed",instance);
   ```

   so the event listener is given the queue that emitted the event.

Answer (score 0):

You can just assign the queue a name when you create it and then the queue will store the name as an instance variable:

```
function queue(name) {
    this.name = name;
    // other constructor code
}

var orderQueue = new queue("orderQueue");.
```

Then, when the last element in the queue is processed by a method on the queue, you can just get the name from the instance data for the queue:

```
process.emit(this.name + "-processed");
```

Comment: thanks for your answer.
this was also my first idea, but i though it is not perfect, because it makes it a bit more complicated or confusing in use.

Comment: @Lutz - Well, there is no way to get a name any other way.  So, your only other choice is to change the design to not require a name.  An object has no idea what variable or variables contain a reference to it.  Javascript simply doesn't work that way.